# how do i change mac folder permission?

Tags: linux, terminal

If I Enter `ls -al` in the Mac terminal, The results are as follows. Like the first line, I want to change `_mysql` to `chowon` but I don't know how to do that.

In fact, several attempts were made through `chmod` commands but were unsuccessful.

[image]

Comment: Did you try : `chown chowon ..`. Add `sudo` if needed.

Comment: it was not working to me.. how i get admin group... i got this error message 'sudo: /etc/sudoers is owned by uid 74, should be 0
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin'

Answer (score 0):

In order to change the permission, you should first have the permission to do that. Mostly those are administrators or `root` users. Please show us the result of `who am i` or try to start the `chmod` command with a `sudo`: `sudo chmod ...`. You'll be asked for a password in order to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try changing the owner and group from `_mysql` and `admin` to `chowon` and `staff` like this :

```
chown chowon ..         # To change the owner
chown chowon:staff ..   # To change the owner and group
```

You need to add `sudo` in front of these commands if you get `Operation not permitted`.

Comment: it was not working... i get this error message 'sudo: /etc/sudoers is owned by uid 74, should be 0
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin'

Comment: you need to have correct permission for this. I tried to change this with root so mine was working.

Comment: can i ask one more? how change my account admin!! ?